# PyPlot - Having difficulty adding axis labels and titles to a plot within a GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I try to incorporate a plot into a GUI, I can't seem to figure out how to set the axis labels and title.

```
self.figure = plt.figure()
self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
ax.hold(False)

ax.plot(xData, yData)

self.canvas.draw()
```

I've tried numerous ways to set the axis labels and titles, and nothing has worked so far.

I've tried:

```
ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111, xlabel=xLabel, ylabel=yLabel, title=fileName)
```

I've also tried:

```
ax.set_xlabel(xLabel)
ax.set_ylabel(yLabel)
ax.set_title(fileName)
```

Neither of these has had any effect.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Those latter lines should work fine.  Did you make sure to put them *before* the call to `self.canvas.draw()`?

Comment: @Ajean:  Yes, however, your suggestion pointed me in the right direction.  I figured out that the label attributes can't be applied to the figure before data is plotted.  Once I moved them after the plot line (but of course before the canvas redraw), everything worked fine.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Ajean pointed me in the right direction.  For those of you having the same problem, the label attributes can't be applied to the figure before data is plotted. Once I moved them after the plot line (but of course before the canvas redraw), everything worked fine.